# How to copy a pixel buffer into a larger one

Tags: c++, arrays, copy, pixel

I’m trying to copy a set of pixels into a larger pixel buffer. Clearly, I’m calculating the coordinates wrong, probably with the strides, but I can’t find what I’m missing. I get a completely messed up result.

So in essence, what I try to achieve is to copy a **RGBA** pixel array into a larger **RGB** array (alpha gets discarded), keeping the strides correctly. See the image below for a visual representation of the expected result.

```
void draw(const uint8_t* tileRGBA, uint8_t* canvasRGB, const int canvasStride,
          const int tileWidth, const int tileHeight)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < tileHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < tileWidth; x++)
        {
            long tileIndex = (4 * x) + (y * tileWidth);
            long canvasIndex = (3 * x) + (y * canvasStride);

            canvasRGB[canvasIndex] = tileRGBA[tileIndex];
            canvasRGB[canvasIndex + 1] = tileRGBA[tileIndex + 1];
            canvasRGB[canvasIndex + 2] = tileRGBA[tileIndex + 2];
        }
    }
}

uint8_t* test(uint32_t* tileRGBA, const int tileWidth, const int tileHeight)
{
    int canvasStride = tileWidth * 5; // 5 is just an arbitrary value for this example, in this case a canvas 5 times the width of the tile

    uint8_t* canvasRGB = new uint8_t[canvasStride * tileHeight * 3];

    draw((uint8_t*)tileRGBA, canvasRGB, canvasStride, tileWidth, tileHeight);

    return canvasRGB;
}
```

[image]

[image]

**SOLVED: Thanks to the comments of Johnny Mopp. It was a matter of brackets.**

This:

```
long tileIndex = (4 * x) + (y * tileWidth)
long canvasIndex = (3 * x) + (y * canvasStride);
```

Must be really this:

```
long tileIndex = 4 * (x + y * tileWidth);
long canvasIndex = 3 * (x + y * canvasStride);
```

Comment: Why don't you use the y-coordinate in your calculation of `tileIndex`?

Comment: Im not getting why `tileIndex = 4*x`?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, it was a typo while writing the question.

Comment: @miradham tile has alpha, 4 bytes per pixel.

Comment: I also don't understand `int canvasStride = tileWidth * 10;`

Comment: What does your completely messed up result look like?

Comment: do you have a `tileStride`?

Comment: the "canvasStride = tileWidth * 10" i just pseudo code, to give an example of creating a canvas which is 10 times the size of the time. Just as an example.

Comment: I guess the most likely problem is that you aren't accessing the RGB values and instead the alpha channel is getting converted to one of your colours.

Comment: @john That's my guess as well. byte order issues for rgba, argb, bgra, etc.

Comment: Is `tileWidth` the width in pixels or bytes?

Comment: both tileWidth and tileHeight in pixels

Comment: So then should the index calculation be `long tileIndex = (4 * x) + (y * tileWidth * 4);`? Because each row is `tileWidth * 4` bytes.

Comment: times 4 is because the Tile is a uint32_t* array (each pixel is 4 bytes to hold RGBA), but to work in the draw function I pass it as a uint8_t* array, therefore to be able to iterate each 4 bytes pixel the x must be multiplied by * 4, and for the canvas must be times 3 as it is a RGB array.

Comment: I agree, but I am suggesting the `tileWidth` calculation also needs to be multiplied by 4. Or rewrite as `long tileIndex = 4 * (x + y * tileWidth);`

Comment: Johnny, this did the trick, See the bottom lines in the question below the images. If you place a formal answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your calculation of the indexes.

To get a 2D index (row,col) in a 1D array you would do:

```
index = ((number_of_columns * row) + col) * sizeof(data)
```

Where `number_of_columns` is the intended number of "columns" in the data - in this case the width of the image. And `sizeof(data)` is the size in bytes of one item in the array - in this case, 4 bytes for RGBA and 3 for RGB. So, as you have determined, it should be:

```
long tileIndex = 4 * (x + y * tileWidth);
long canvasIndex = 3 * (x + y * canvasStride);
```

---

You can do away with the `sizeof` multiplication if you can represent the data as a single item. For example, in your case, create 2 structs:

```
struct RGB {
    uint8_t r,g,b;
};
struct RGBA {
    uint8_t r,g,b,a;
};
```

Then pass the parameters as arrays of these structs:

```
void draw(const RGBA* tileRGBA, RGB* canvasRGB, const int canvasStride, const int tileWidth, const int tileHeight)
```

Then the calculation simplifies to:

```
long tileIndex = x + y * tileWidth;
long canvasIndex = x + y * canvasStride;
```